# drag a div already in fixed center from same position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JqueryUI Draggable to move a div which is at center bottom of a page and is fixed. the problem is whenever i start to drag it. Its position changes all of a sudden to bottom left and then i have to drag it from bottom left. I would like to start the drag from the same center position but not able to achieve so.

The code i made is

```
function make_my_toolbar_draggable()
{
    jQuery('#mx-toolbar').draggable({

    create: function(){

    },  
    start: function (event, ui) {

    },  
    drag: function(event, ui) 
            {


                var layout_top=jQuery(this).position().top-110;
                var layout_left=jQuery(this).position().left+20;
                var temp_top=jQuery(this).position().top-350;
                var temp_left=jQuery(this).position().left-60;
                jQuery('#mx-toolbar-mini').css('left',layout_left);   
                jQuery('#emb-section-chooser').css('left',temp_left);  
                jQuery('#emb-section-chooser').css('top',temp_top);
                jQuery('#mx-toolbar-mini').css('top',layout_top); 
                jQuery('#mx-toolbar-mini,#emb-section-chooser').css('right','auto'); 

            }

    });
}
```

I am dragging few more containers along with the main one so thats a different code above and works fine. But the drag position should be from bottom center fixed instead of bottom left which it all of a sudden moves to when i try to drag it.

Comment: Is your #mx-toolbar ID set to position:relative or position:absolute initially? You might need to redefine the  type of positioning used in your jQuery CSS definitions inside the function on drag.

Comment: its defined to position fixed

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want it's `x` or `left` position to remain fixed, and you only want to drag along `y`, so that the user can only move the item up or down?

Comment: Could you make use of `containment` option, either by it's `parent` or `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`?